# Rolling Standard Deviation

Tags: stata

I use Stata for estimating rolling standard deviation of ROA (using 4 window in previous year). Now, I would like to keep only those rolling standard deviation that has at least 3 observation (out of 4) in the ROA. How can I do this using Stata?

**ROA               roa_sd**
.                  .
.              . 
.              . 
.0108869           .
.0033411           .
.0032814     .0053356 (this value should be missing as it was calculated using only 2 valid value)
.0030827     .0043739
.0029793     .0038275

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: ROA is not explained here. It appears incidental to the question, but at the same time it's best not to assume that people who might answer are working in exactly the same field as you.

Comment: Was this cross-posted elsewhere? This exact question is answered [here on a blog](http://statadaily.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/rolling-standard-deviations-and-missing-observations/).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is answered on the [blog post](http://statadaily.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/rolling-standard-deviations-and-missing-observations/) I link to above in the comments. You can use `rolling` and then add an additional screen to discard sigma when the number of observations doesn't meet your threshold.

But for simple calculations like sigma and beta (i.e., standard deviation and univariate regression coefficient) you can do much better with a more manual approach. Compare the `rolling` solution with my manual solution.

```
/* generate panel by adpating the linked code */
clear
set obs 20000
gen date = _n
gen id = floor((_n - 1) / 20) + 1
gen roa = int((100) * runiform())
replace roa = . in 1/4
replace roa = . in 10/12
replace roa = . in 18/20

/* solution with rolling */
/* http://statadaily.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/rolling-standard-deviations-and-missing-observations/ */
timer on 1
xtset id date
rolling sd2 = r(sd), window(4) keep(date) saving(f2, replace): sum roa
merge 1:1 date using f2, nogenerate keepusing(sd2)
xtset id date
gen tag = missing(l3.roa) + missing(l2.roa) + missing(l1.roa) + missing(roa) > 1
gen sd = sd2 if (tag == 0)
timer off 1

/* my solution */
timer on 2
rolling_sd roa, window(4) minimum(3)
timer off 2

/* compare */
timer list
list in 1/50
```

I show the manual solution is much faster.

```
. /* compare */
. timer list
   1:    132.38 /        1 =     132.3830
   2:      0.10 /        1 =       0.0990
```

Save the following as `rolling_sd.ado` in your personal ado file directory (or in your current working directory). I'm sure that someone could further streamline this code. Note that this code has the additional advantage of meeting the minimum data requirements at the front edge of the window (i.e., calculates sigma with first three observations, rather than waiting for all four).

```
*! 0.2 Richard Herron 3/30/14
    * added minimum data requirement
*! 0.1 Richard Herron 1/12/12

program rolling_sd
    version 11.2
    syntax varlist(numeric), window(int) minimum(int)

    * get dependent and indpendent vars from varlist
    tempvar n miss xs x2s nonmiss1 nonmiss2 sigma1 sigma2 
    local w = `window' 
    local m = `minimum'

    * generate cumulative sums and missing values
    xtset
    bysort `r(panelvar)' (`timevar'): generate `n' = _n
    by `r(panelvar)': generate `miss' = sum(missing(`varlist'))
    by `r(panelvar)': generate `xs' = sum(`varlist')
    by `r(panelvar)': generate `x2s' = sum(`varlist' * `varlist')

    * generate variance 1 (front of window)
    generate `nonmiss1' = `n' - `miss'
    generate `sigma1' = sqrt((`x2s' - `xs'*`xs'/`nonmiss1')/(`nonmiss1' - 1)) if inrange(`nonmiss1', `m', `w') & !missing(`nonmiss1')

    * generate variance 2 (back of window, main part)
    generate `nonmiss2' = `w' - s`w'.`miss'
    generate `sigma2' = sqrt((s`w'.`x2s' - s`w'.`xs'*s`w'.`xs'/`nonmiss2')/(`nonmiss2' - 1)) if inrange(`nonmiss2', `m', `w') & !missing(`nonmiss2')

    * return standard deviation
    egen sigma = rowfirst(`sigma2' `sigma1')
end
```